# Unable to show data in ng-repeat using factory

Tags: html, angularjs

I have created a factory and making $HTTP request.I have used ng-repeat to show data.Getting `data from factory` and adding it to $scope variable in controller is unable to show data.The Code is as mentioned below.

I used console.log to get the json returned and it is as mentioned below

**JSON**:

```
[{"searchName":"this is test Job","id":"2"},{"searchName":"Job new","id":"1"}]
```

**Angular JS Code**:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var formApp = angular.module("saveSearch",[]);
  formApp.controller("saveSearchController",function($scope,saveServiceSearch)
  {
     saveServiceSearch.getLatestSaveSearch().then(function(data){
      $scope.saveSearches  = data;
     });
   });

 formApp.factory('saveServiceSearch', function($http) {
    return  {
               getLatestSaveSearch: function() {
               var url = "/job_search_crud.html?act=gtSearchSv";
               return promise = $http.get(url,{cache: false});
               promise.success(function(data,status, headers, config){
               return $data;
               });
             promise.error(function(data,status, headers, config){
                 alert("::Request Failed::");
                 });
             }
           };
     });


 </script>
```

**HTML**:

```
<html>
<body ng-app="formApp">
<div ng-controller="saveSearchController">

<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="saveSearch in saveSearches" >
    <td>{{saveSearch.searchName}}</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: In your `getLatestSaveSearch` function, you have set your success and error function after returning your promise.

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var formApp = angular.module("saveSearch",[]);

  formApp.controller("saveSearchController",function($scope,saveServiceSearch)
  {
     saveServiceSearch.getLatestSaveSearch().then(function(data){
        $scope.saveSearches = data;
     });
  });

 formApp.factory('saveServiceSearch', function($http) {
    return  {
               getLatestSaveSearch: function() {
               var url = "/job_search_crud.html?act=gtSearchSv";
               return $http.get(url,{cache: false});
             }
       }});
 </script>
```

Comment: added the promise after success/error callback still unable to get data in ng-repeat

Comment: Take a look at my edit and add a debugger before the line "$scope.saveSearches = data;" to see what happens to data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this using `$q`

```
myModule.factory('saveServiceSearch', function($q, $timeout, $http) {  
      var getLatestSaveSearch = function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        var url = "/job_search_crud.html?act=gtSearchSv";
        var data = $http.get(url,{cache: false});
        $timeout(function() {
          deferred.resolve(data);
        }, 2000);

        return deferred.promise;
      };

      return {
        getLatestSaveSearch: getLatestSaveSearch
      };

    });
```

Comment: same problem still persist unable to show data in ng-repeat